# Как разобратся с соседями элемента в DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

В статье по DOM прочитал что у элемента есть соседние элементы слева и с права, как это понять? Я представляю DOM в виде дерева то есть у каждого элемента есть родитель и могут быть потомки, а что такое соседи понять не могу, а тем более что к тому же есть соседи правые и левые... Просветите меня в этом вопросе кому не трудно.

Comment: Дети того же родителя: слева - идущие в списке детей родителя до текущего элемента, справа - после.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возьмём за основу следующий код:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Чтобы правильно представить дерево, можно посмотреть на него не сверху вниз, а слева направо: `DIV > UL > LI`.
У элемента `ul` есть родитель `div` и потомки `li`.
А среди `li` есть соседние элементы: для `<li>2</li>` есть два соседа - левый сосед `<li>1</li>`, а правый `<li>3</li>`.

Про навигацию по этим элементам средствами `Javascript` можно прочитать по сссылке: [Навигация по DOM-элементам](https://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom)

Comment: с `<li>` я понял, а для UL < DIV будет сосед слева? и для UL > LI будет сосед справа? правильно я понял?

Comment: @perfect нет, у `UL` соседей нет, живет один

Comment: @Igor а если у `<div>` есть три списка внутри? то второй список будет иметь соседа слева и справа?

Comment: @perfect - будет

Comment: @Igor спасибо теперь все понятно

Comment: @perfect, нужно уточнить что соседями могут быть не только элементы, но и ноды текста и/или комментариев. Можно фильтровать только элементы, вызвав `nextElementSibling`/`previousElementSibling`, но лучше знать это.

Comment: @Other спасибо учту

Answer (score 2):

Насколько могу судить, в вопросе подразумеваются не соседи как таковые, а (siblings) потомки от одного родителя. Графически это можно отобразить так:

```
           родитель
    __________|__________          
   |          |          |
потомок_1  потомок_2  потомок_3
```

где у **потомка_2**, есть два "соседа" слева (потомок_1) и справа (потомок_3).